# Angular route 'data' is empty in ActivatedRoute.snapshot when AoT is enabled

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-aot

I have a few routes in my Angular 7 app that have a `data` property, used for different purposes - retrieved from `activatedRoute.snapshot.data`. The issue I'm having is that everything works as expected in development (JIT compiler) but once I move to production with Ahead-of-time, the `data` is an empty object.

Bare minimum to reproduce: add a `data` property to a route, e.g.

in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'foo',
        component: fooComponent,
        data: {
            bar: 'bar'
        }
    }
];
...
```

then `console.log()` the `activatedRoute.snapshot.data` in the component matching the route e.g.

in `foo.component.ts`:

```
...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data);
}
```

With `ng serve` (JIT), you should get the `data` in console.
With `ng serve --aot=true` (Ahead-of-time) `data` is an empty object in console.

There is not much else I could try apart from disabling AoT in production, which is not ideal due to the performance benefits. It looks like an issue with AoT itself but here I am wondering if someone else has faced and solved the same issue before?

Comment: Try instead `this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(someData => console.log(data));`. https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data

Comment: are you just passing static strings in the route data? Are there any console errors?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky unfortunately the same... empty object!

Comment: @inorganik yes, same as in my dummy code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes need to be exported to work with `AoT` enabled

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'foo',
        component: fooComponent,
        data: {
            bar: 'bar'
        }
    }
];
```

when running the code in the question, there were warnings that weren't exactly descriptive of what the issue was, but that piece of information together with the issue linked in @user1254498's answer (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5754) I was able to figure out a fix.

> WARNING in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 112:9550-9556
>   "export 'ɵ0' (imported as 'i65') was not found in './modules/pip/pip.module'

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this issue : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5754

Quick solution:

```
// app.component.ts
constructor(private router: Router) {
  // reset routes
  router.resetConfig(routes);
}
```

Comment: not the same issue, but the information in that thread helped me finding the solution - have an upvote on me, thanks